# OpenSSL 3.0 migration converting array to EVPPkey

Tags: c++, openssl

I have the following deprecated code:

```
EVP_PKEY *convertByteArrayToEvpPkey(const uint8_t *i_KeyByteArray, size_t i_Length, bool isPrivateKey)
{
    EC_KEY *ecKey = EC_KEY_new_by_curve_name(NID_X9_62_prime256v1);
    if (ecKey == NULL)
    {
        errMsg("Initialization of EC key failed");
    }

    EVP_PKEY *key = EVP_PKEY_new();
    if (key == NULL)
    {
        errMsg("Allocation of public key failed");
    }

    if (EVP_PKEY_set1_EC_KEY(key, ecKey) != 1)
    {
        errMsg("Setting EC key in public key failed");
    }

    if (isPrivateKey)
    {
        BIGNUM *bignum = BN_bin2bn(i_KeyByteArray, i_Length, NULL);
        if (bignum == NULL)
        {
            errMsg("Conversion to BIGNUM failed");
        }

        // EVP_PKEY points to ecKey, so changing ecKey changes the returned value
        if (EC_KEY_set_private_key(ecKey, bignum) != 1)
        {
            errMsg("Setting private key failed");
        }

        BN_free(bignum);
    }
    else
    {
        if (d2i_PublicKey(EVP_PKEY_EC, &key, &i_KeyByteArray, i_Length) == NULL)
        {
            errMsg("Loading public key failed");
        }
    }

    return key;
}
```

I want to change `EC_KEY_set_private_key`, since it's deprecated but it's not clear in the documentation what will be used instead.

I found this alternative in the documentation but I'm still not sure with it:
[https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_fromdata.html#:~:text=Creating%20an%20ECC%20keypair%20using%20raw%20key%20data](https://www.openssl.org/docs/man3.1/man3/EVP_PKEY_fromdata.html#:%7E:text=Creating%20an%20ECC%20keypair%20using%20raw%20key%20data)

```
int main()
{
    EVP_PKEY_CTX *ctx;
    EVP_PKEY *pkey = NULL;
    BIGNUM *priv;
    OSSL_PARAM_BLD *param_bld;
    OSSL_PARAM *params = NULL;
    int exitcode = 0;

    priv = BN_bin2bn(priv_data, sizeof(priv_data), NULL);

    param_bld = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_new();
    if (priv != NULL && param_bld != NULL && OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_utf8_string(param_bld, "group", "prime256v1", 0) && OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_BN(param_bld, "priv", priv) && OSSL_PARAM_BLD_push_octet_string(param_bld, "pub", pub_data, sizeof(pub_data)))
        params = OSSL_PARAM_BLD_to_param(param_bld);

    ctx = EVP_PKEY_CTX_new_from_name(NULL, "EC", NULL);
    if (ctx == NULL || 
     params == NULL || 
     EVP_PKEY_fromdata_init(ctx) <= 0 ||
     EVP_PKEY_fromdata(ctx, &pkey, EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR, params) <= 0)
    {
        exitcode = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        /* Do what you want with |pkey| */
    }

 
    //clear then exit
}
```

Will this do the trick ? I'm not sure whether `EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR` in `EVP_PKEY_fromdata(ctx, &pkey, EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR, params)` is what I need to load the private key array into EVP_PKEY structure

Comment: Didn't try compiling it, but it looks ok to me - except it is not clear from you code snippet where `pub_data` or `priv_data` have come from. `EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR` is described in the docs as "Any keypair components will be selected. This includes the private key, public key and key parameters.", and you are supplying all 3 of those - so it should be fine.

Comment: It's in the example of OpenSSL link (at the bottom of the page), he provided 2 keys "pub_data" and "priv_data" to store in the EVP_PKEY structure.  I guess that's why he used the `EVP_PKEY_PAIR` selection as a parameter but I want to store only the private key as I did before with `EC_KEY_set_private_key`.

Comment: Ah, I see. In general, many key types require that both the public and the private keys are present. However, OpenSSL does tolerate an EC key without the public key part (although if you attempt any operations that need the public key then they will fail). The OpenSSL supplied providers will tolerate you specifying `EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR` but only actually giving the private key. 3rd party providers might not do so. `EVP_PKEY_KEYPAIR` is just a macro for `( EVP_PKEY_PUBLIC_KEY | OSSL_KEYMGMT_SELECT_PRIVATE_KEY )` so you can just specify `OSSL_KEYMGMT_SELECT_PRIVATE_KEY` if you want to be more...

Comment: ...explicit. 3rd party providers may or may not be more tolerant of that.